# Running ie10, ie11 at same time for testing?

Tags: testing, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I recently installed ie11 on my Windows7 machine and do browser testing for all versions of ie on it in the document. I also do tests on Browserstack. I have client now that INSISTS I test on ie10 directly.

As you know, Windows won't let you run multiple version if ie, un-install ie directly, or reinstall an older version when a newer version is already installed. I don't want to have to uninstall/reinstall ie11, reinstall/install ie10.

Is there a work around where I can run both version without have to uninstall one or the other?

Comment: I recommend downloading [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage). It will emulate from IE5.5 to IE9. My only gripe with it is, caches can't be cleared, you could workaround this using proxies though.

Answer (score 19):

On [modern.ie](http://www.modern.ie/en-US/virtualization-tools) you can find free virtual machines for every version of Internet Explorer.

Comment: I think they're an affiliate of BrowserStack, who actually provide the service. Nevertheless, good solution @ZippyV.

Comment: @JackWilliams Microsoft does promote BrowserStack but the free virtual machines have nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 1):

Press F12 and you can go backward to previous versions of IE (click on browser mode). First go to the website and then change browser mode (the opposite order won't work)

Comment: If his client wants it tested in IE10, he better test it in the real IE10.

Comment: i wouldnt really recommend this as there case like popup pages from the backward modes will not persist and rechange back to the current IE version. whatever it is, its back to what the requirements are.

Comment: One of my colleagues is getting a bug in IE 10 that I can't reproduce using the IE 10 browser mode. Testing in a emulated version doesn't always work.

Comment: Yea it's not the same. The rendering engine is still IE 11, even if you pick IE 10 browser & document modes. From what I can tell they wrapped it - so it's similar, but the underlying engine operates using the latest standards.  You cannot reliably debug IE versions with the latest version. You need the actual version of Internet Exploder with which you wish to test.