# How to run multiple version of IEs (IE10, IE11) on same machine without using any virtual as well third party tools

Tags: internet-explorer, testing, web, browser

I need to test/debug a Web application on IE10 as well as IE11. I want to install/run two different version on same machine without using any virtual PC/machine software or third party tools (since No permission to install third party tools)

Note: Without using third party or Virtual PC(or similar software)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running ie10, ie11 at same time for testing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057739/running-ie10-ie11-at-same-time-for-testing)

Comment: The linked question states that a single copy of Windows won't let you install more than one. So you need multiple Windows installations (virtual or otherwise).

Comment: I wont consider it duplicate as it clearly mention without using third party tools. As far as I know we wont able to install multiple version at a time, thats why looking for any hack or trick that will do my work.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft does not provide a way to run more than one version of Internet Explorer on the same Windows installation, so the only options are to use third party tools or to have more than one copy of Windows (either using virtual machines or by partitioning a hard drive and dual-booting.) It's not possible without using one of those two methods.